# Unwanted screen change when updating redux state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

When I try to change a state in my user reducer, I get an unwanted screen change. I don't know why it is happening and nothing in my code is causing the screen change.

```
//The users reducer
  case "UPDATE_USER":
      state = action.user;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
```

```
//This is the class that is calling the action
 componentDidMount() {
    // Updates your user data after the match ends... This is when you are still on the rating screen
    this.props.socket.getSocket().on("iWasRated", user => {
      alert("I was rated");
      this.props.dispatch(handleUpdateUser(user));
      this.props.socket.getSocket().off("iWasRated");
    });
  }
```

When the dispatched is called, the redux state should just change and no navigation should happen. When the redux state changes, it takes me to another screen. Am I doing something wrong?